# opencv ArUco library using circle object detected

Tags: android, opencv

I am new to Open CV, So please help me.

How can get feature points using ArUco library for circle object?
Is it possible or not?

possibly, share your code experience

Comment: any one help me

Comment: What do you mean by circle object? ArUco detects markers. See the following [tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d6d/tutorial_table_of_content_aruco.html).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you are looking to do with feature points.
So here are some useful links regarding that.

[What is feature points?](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_meaning/py_features_meaning.html#features-meaning)

[Android: Detect feature points and display camera images with OpenGL ES](http://www.anandmuralidhar.com/blog/android/corners/)

[Feature Detection and Description using openCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html)